# How to trigger Vue Apollo Query update when skip is true?

Tags: vue.js, vue-apollo

if anyone of you using Vue Apollo please help, if I do something like this,

```js
export default {
    apollo: {
        statsAndProfile: {
            query: STATS_AND_PROFILE_QUERY,
            update({stats, profile}) {
                this.stats = stats
                this.profile = profile
            },
            skip: localStorage.isAuth === 'false'
        },
    },
    data(){
       return {
          stats: null
          profile: null
       }
    }

}
```

and then in one of the components do `created() { this.$apollo.queries.statsAndProfile.start() }` it does not update `this.stats` or `this.profile`, update only works when skip is false from the start. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

The query results are stored in the component's `data()` so you can update it directly in the body of the `skip()` function:

```js
statsAndProfile: {
  skip() {
    if (localStorage.isAuth === 'false') {
      this.status = null;
      this.profile = null;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  },
},
```